# Backup of ubuntu 22.04 LTS to onedrive

Tags: backup, sync, systemback

I have a query regarding the setup of the backup of my Ubuntu on OneDrive. Is there any way to backup Ubuntu to OneDrive automatically at regular intervals?
When I opened the backup app from the Ubuntu utility, the following appeared on the screen:

[image]

Is there a way to make system's backup to OneDrive through this?

Comment: I don't think there is an One Drive option, only Google Drive, Network Attached Storage (NAS), or USB.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to backup Ubuntu to OneDrive automatically at regular intervals?
> When I opened the backup app from the Ubuntu utility, the following appeared on the screen:
>
> ...
>
> Is there a way to make system's backup to OneDrive through this?

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

You need to first install the OneDrive Client for Linux, however even doing that will not make it available to the Ubuntu backup application as there is no integration between the two applications - and this would require development by the Ubuntu team (not me) to make that integration occur.

To install the OneDrive Client for Linux correctly on Ubuntu platforms, you must follow the correct installation procedure as documented here: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md

One the client is installed on Ubuntu, you then can configure the client in such a way to upload the data that you wish to backup to OneDrive on the regular interval that you require. Please refer to the documentation on GitHub for usage references and examples to assist in doing this.

Alternatively, if you need a GUI to assist with the client configuration, you need to review and install https://github.com/bpozdena/OneDriveGUI

Comment: You will also need to have python3-requests-oauthlib (or the version appropriate for your version of Ubuntun).

sudo apt get python3-requests-oauthlib

Answer (score 1):

I see this in Ubuntu 22.04 and Déjà Dupe v44.0.

[image]

Comment: I wanted to get version 44 on my Ubuntu 22.04, but according to this it's not possible https://askubuntu.com/questions/1491869/can-i-install-the-latest-stable-deja-dup-v44-on-20-04. Did you do some black magic or there's some straight forward way to  do this?

Comment: No. I don't recall doing anything special. Perhaps I installed it with apt instead of snap?

Comment: For me just the snap has the right version. (`sudo snap install deja-dup --classic`)